React passing state to child class from parent function
I am a React-Idiot more at home in other parts of the tech stack, building a super simple React 18 app with two components: Home is the calling function, and ImageDisplay is a React class. I need bidirectional communication between them. I managed to get it to work from Home to ImageDisplay downwards using properties and state, but I need to send a trigger back up from ImageDisplay to Home.
Essentially Home is the main page with a button. As soon as the button is clicked, ImageDisplay makes an asynchronous backend call. Whilst this is happening, I want the button in the Home function to be disabled to prevent to user from triggering a second AWS Lambda call being executed. I am using a boolean isLoading for this. And as soon as the axios call has successfully completed, set isLoading back to false again so that button can be enabled again.
I have been struggling myself stupid. I tried some Redux options. I am now on context passing. I am open to any sensible solution. Code looks something like this:
import {createContext} from "react";

export const MyContext = createContext(false);

function Home() {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(useContext(MyContext));

    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                disabled={isLoading}
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                    setIsShow(true);
                }}>
                Generate with Bedrock
            </Button>
            <div>
                <MyContext.Provider value={isLoading}>
                    {<ImageDisplay prompt={prompt}/>}
                </MyContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;

export default class ImageDisplay extends React.Component<{ prompt: string }> {

    state = {
        isLoading: true
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        // => load stuff
        // Whilst stuff is loading, send message back up to calling function to disable button

        // axios.get('URL', {
        //     ...
        //         this.setState({
        //             isLoading: false
        //         });
        // }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.isLoading}>
                    <div>
                        {/*<HTML_STUFF goes here></HTML_STUFF>*/}
                    </div>
                </MyContext.Provider>
            </>
        );

    }
}


To pass the data from child to parent to can pass function as prop to child and calling it from child will trigger it in function.
function Home() {
    
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
      const setLoadingValue = () =>{
        setLoading(false);
      }
    
      return (
          <div>
              <Button
                  disabled={isLoading}
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => {
                      setIsShow(true);
                  }}>
                  Generate with Bedrock
              </Button>
              <div>
                <ImageDisplay prompt={prompt} setLoadingValue={setLoadingValue}/>
              </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Home;
    
    function ImageDisplay () {
    
      useEffect(() =>{
        //make networkcall
        // axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        //   .then((res) => {
            props.setLoading();
       //   setUsers(res.data);
    // })
      }, []);
    
     return (
                <>
                        <div>
                            {/*<HTML_STUFF goes here></HTML_STUFF>*/}
                        </div>
                </>
     )
    
    }

